# Printing in React-Native Expo

Tags: javascript, react-native, printing, expo, unhandled-promise-rejection

I am using expo and I want to convert a dynamic html into a pdf so that it can be printable.Here is my implementation

```
 export const DynamicTable = () => {  //my component
 const { employeedata, business } = useContext(AuthContext);  //some data i want from the context api
 var table = `    //table i want to map dynamic data into
 <div id="invoice-POS">
<center id="top">
  <div class="logo"></div>
  <div class="info"> 
     <h2 id="info">${business?.name}</h2>
  </div>
</center> 
<div id="mid">
  <div class="info">
    <h2>Contact Info</h2>
    <p> 
        <span>Address : street city, state 0000</span>
        <span>Email   : JohnDoe@gmail.com</span>
        <span>Phone   : 555-555-5555</span>    
    </p>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="bot">

                <div id="table">
                    <table>
                        <tr class="tabletitle">
                            <td class="item"><h2>Item</h2></td>
                            <td class="Hours"><h2>Qty</h2></td>
                            <td class="Rate"><h2>Sub Total</h2></td>
                        </tr>
                </table>
                </div>
            </div>
             </div>
                 `;

  const receipthtml = `
  <html>
 <head>
 </head>
 <body> 
 ${table}   //table above
</body>
</html>
 `;

 console.log(receipthtml)
   return receipthtml;
};

const print = async () => {   //this function is called on click,,,it is what is in order the expo doc when you want to print something
await Print.printAsync({
  html:DynamicTable(),  //my component
  base64:true,
  useMarkupFormatter,
  
});
 };
```

however when i run the code i get the following error

```
WARN  Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0):
```

Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:

1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
   See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and fix this problem

How do i fix this error?